# Permission denied when copying on a fileshare in Finder, but copying via command line works

Tags: mac-osx, samba, finder

I'm trying to copy files on a SMB fileshare.  When I attempt to copy the files in Finder, I get the following error:

```
 The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items.
```

Copying via Terminal.app (using a simple `cp` command) works just fine.

Permissions on the folders (as seen from the computer attached to the fileshare) are as follows:

Source:

```
 dr-xr-x---   2 smokris  staff    16384 Oct 13 10:55 .
 dr-xr-x---@ 61 smokris  staff    16384 Oct 13 10:56 ..
 -r--r-----   1 smokris  staff    53970 Oct 13 10:55 ._IMG_3823.JPG
 -r--r-----@  1 smokris  staff  3135600 Oct 13 10:55 IMG_3823.JPG
```

Destination:

```
 drwxrwx---  2 smokris  staff    16384 Apr  9 10:17 .
 drwxrwx---  3 smokris  staff    16384 Apr  9 10:15 ..
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug introduced by the recent 10.6.3 release (10.6.2 worked just fine for the same test case).

Adding `unix extensions = no` to the `[global]` section in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` solved the problem for me (found on http://splatdot.com/fixing-snow-leopard-10-6-3-samba-write-access/, which unfortunately wasn't on the first few pages of the google search results for the Finder error message when I posted this question).

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

This could come from extensible attribute set on the file (@ sign on the line)
You can do ls -l@ to see them.

Do a copy of the file in the finder, them remove extended attribute with
xattr attr_name file (do ls -l@ to see attr_name)

Then try to copy the file on the SMB share.